# Time complexity, Big-O for this function?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, big-o-notation

```
def f(n):
    if n < 100000:
        return 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n*n; i++){
        return f(n-1)
    }
```

**What is the time complexity?**

---

My answer is $O((n!)^2)$. Here's my thought process:

1. The for loop will be running $n^2$ the first time.
2. However, during the first loop (i.e., $i = 0$), it will call $f(n-1)$, hence
   the next for loop will be $(n-1)^2$.
3. This will keep going until $n <10000$ (base case).  Assuming $n$ is very
   huge, the number of calls for each function to base case is essentially $n$ times.
4. Now, considering all the for loops, the total number of calls is essentially $n^2 \cdot (n-1)^2 \cdot (n-2)^2 \cdots 1!$ (there will be a total of $n$ times multiplication, and each multiplication will be $n-1$ of the previous one because of $f(n-1)$ call).

Comment: There are clearly some braces missing in your code, so nobody knows what that function does - but my best guess is it is O(n).

Comment: What kind of programming language is this? The first 3 lines look like Python but then line 4 takes a sharp turn towards C (or towards C sharp?—pun intended).

Comment: @dkaeae It's pseudocode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a system behind the magic of algorithm analysis?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis)

Answer (score 4):

It runs in time $O(n)$. Remember that a function only `return`s once.  In each call to `f`, the `for` loop is immediately terminated at `i=0` by the `return` statement, so the function body is equivalent to

```
if n < 100000
    return 0;
else
    return f(n-1);
```

However, your answer of $O((n!)^2)$ is not wrong: $(n!)^2$ is a huge overestimate of the running time, but big-$O$ essentially means "at most this much."

Comment: ohh yeah I didn't see that the for loop is useless because of the return statement

Comment: what if i take away the return part? what will be the time complexity